# Get secure file download ticket via .NET API

Tags: c#, download

Using the Microsoft.TeamFoundation .NET client APIs, how can I get a download ticket for a secure file from TFS 2017u2?

Using the [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTasks.WebApi nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi/15.130.0-preview), I puffed up the below code in a console app. It successfully retrieves all the metadata and associated properties entered in TFS for the secure file. However, despite passing the "includeDownloadTicket" argument as "true" to the GetSecureFileAsync method, the Ticket property is always null.

I thought perhaps it was a permissions issue but I am in the TFS Admin role and also specifically assigned myself as an admin to the file entry in the web interface.

```
var credentials = new VssCredentials();
var projectName = "{myProjectName}";
var secureFileId = new Guid("{theSecureFileId}");
var tfsUri = new Uri("https://{tfsBox}/{collection}");
var connection = new VssConnection(tfsUri, credentials);
var taskAgentClient = connection.GetClient<TaskAgentHttpClient>();
var projectClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
var project = await projectClient.GetProject(projectName, true);
var secureFile = await taskAgentClient.GetSecureFileAsync(project.Id, secureFileId, true);
var secureFileTicket = secureFile.Ticket;

if (secureFileTicket == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "No download ticket was provided by the TFS for the requested Secure File.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: The minimum build Agent Version is 2.116.0, have you checked this? Not familiar with the client API, take a look at this [Secure Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=carlowahlstedt.SecureFiles) task which support on TFS2017. You could refer the source code(https://github.com/carlowahlstedt/SecureFiles_VSTS_Task/blob/master/SecureFiles/PreInstallSecureFiles.js), which may be helful to you.

Comment: Thanks @Chamberlain. In this case I'm not running this from an agent but actually from a separate .NET application. The linked task is using the Node API and not the .NET client libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thought is right. This is related to the permission. For security reason, normal users are limited to download the secure files. The permission you can set is "Reader", "User" and "Administrator" for normal users while it requires "ViewSecrets" permission to include the download ticket.

So you cannot download the secure files for now.

Comment: Thank you, @Eddie-Chen-MSFT. If it's a permissions issue, how does the node task Chamberlain referenced above (https://github.com/carlowahlstedt/SecureFiles_VSTS_Task/blob/master/SecureFiles/PreInstallSecureFiles.js) work from a build agent? I tried having my console app authenticate as my build agent user but it still could not get a ticket yet if I use a build task like that one, my agent is able to download the files.I did see an entry in the debug log of the build task that said the "secure file ticket for id {guidHere} = null" but it still downloaded ok, so is the ticket not even used?

Comment: @pwil301 The task use getSecureFileTicket() method to get the ticket. When you refer to a secure file endpoint in the build task and run the build, the ticket is passed to the build as an environment variable like SECUREFILE_TICKET_SecureFileId and this method just get the value of this environment variable. The ticket is not generated by the code in the task. Are you sure that you see the ticket is null and the file is downloaded successfully?

Comment: @Eddie-Chen-MSFT Interesting! Then is it correct to say the .NET API I'm using above is actually intended for use on a build agent and not from a separate .NET application as I am trying to do? Do we know if MS intends to make it available? Regarding the node build task, the debug log shows: "2018-02-27T14:07:21.3331370Z ##[debug]secure file ticket for id a0bffebf-16b8-4b2a-9b80-34f0d7d6f50d = null"