# How to use variable to specify Secure File input value in TFS 2017u2 Build and Release task

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

When using the "securefile" input type in a build/release task (custom or out of the box) in Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2017 update 2, how can I use a variable to specify the name of the secure file I wish to download? Alternatively, how can I force TFS to issue a secure file download ticket for a file not known until runtime?

Out of the box, the secure file input type forces you to pick from a dropdown list of values and disallows entering any characters not in the list (including the names of variables).

Our workflows include generating new x509 certificates and pushing them into the Secure Files library and setting properties on the entries such as CN, thumbprint, SAN, etc. We then need to pull the file down to an agent for tasks later in the workflow. However, because the file is not in the library at design time, we cannot select it in the list.

We tried implementing a custom download task. However, if you don't use the "securefile" input type and specify the exact file you need when defining the build, TFS won't issue a download ticket to the agent and you thus can't download the actual file (only metadata).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the extension [Download Secure File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mattlabrum.build-task) on your TFS.

But unfortunately, variables can not be used in download secure file task.

There's an issue submitted here: [Enable to use a variable to specify the secure file to download](https://github.com/mlabrum/vsts-download-secure-file/issues/9) which suggests this feature, you can follow up.

And also there is a [User Voice here submitted](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32752684-access-secure-files-from-net-client-library) to suggest the feature which download secure file with the REST API, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future.

Related threads for your reference:

- [Download secure file with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175519/download-secure-file-with-powershell)
- [Get secure file download ticket via .NET API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916924/get-secure-file-download-ticket-via-net-api)

Comment: Thanks @Andy-Li-MSFT. Not the answer I was hoping for, however. Is the code for the input types (like securefile) open sourced somewhere that we can at least see what TFS is doing with it internally? I'm curious how it knows when to issue a ticket or not. I added to an issue on the vsts tasks site as you mentioned: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6885